# How to check the message which server sends you after you connected to it via netcat (nc) or telnet?

Tags: bash

For example, I am connecting to the server via netcat:

`$ nc localhost 30002`

When the connection is established, the host sends me the following message

```
$ nc localhost 30002
Hello! Please name yourself!
```

...and waiting for my response.

I need to write a Bash script which checks the message server sends me and then do something:

```
#!/bin/bash

nc localhost 30002

if [ "<the message which server sent me when I connected to it>" = "Hello! Please name yourself!" ]
then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash command to read from network socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283209/bash-command-to-read-from-network-socket)

Comment: Your `nc` command in your script will simply run until the remote end closes the connection; _then_ your `if` statement will execute. If that's all you need, the proposed duplicate should be sufficient. If you need the connection to stay open, please [edit] to clarify your requirements.